# have webpage prompt with squid and apache?

Tags: apache-2.2, squid

How would one set up a system where any web client first has to log on, via a webpage, and then can access whatever page they want to access.

I know Proxies can require authentication, but what if what is wanted is a webpage itself asking for a username and password?

I'm interested in different solutions to this, involving squid and apache

Answer (score 0):

if I'm correct, it call "[Captive Portal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captive_portal)". a good firewall like pfSense can do that job.
don't forget to read the limitations from wikipedia before to implement that.

here [enter link description here](http://forum.pfsense.org/index.php?topic=7397.0)